# Git IdentityFile in config

Tags: git, identity-management

When I need to add new identity I must edit ".ssh/config" file manually. I'm just wondering is there a git command to add "IdentityFile" (with path to key) in "config" file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding identities isn't supposed to be a common thing. The way it's supposed to work is that you have one key-pair as your identity and use its public key for everything. Also, those are an SSH concept, not a git concept. For both of those reasons, git doesn't have a command to do that automatically.